# not work jquery mobile methods inside $.get()

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

not work jquery mobile methods inside $.get()
like below code didnot work, also $("#orderproduct").dialog("close"); didnot work

```
$(document).on("pagechange", function(e, data) {
    if ( typeof data.options.pageData != "undefined") {
        $pid = data.options.pageData.pid;
    }


    //add product to order basket---------------------
    $("#addtobasket").bind("tap",function(){
        $q = $("#quantity").val();
        if($q < 1) {
            alert("order.");
            return false;
        }

        $.mobile.loading('show', {
            text : 'register ',
            textVisible : true,
            theme : 'b',
            html : ""
        });

        $.get($PAYLA_SERVER+"components/pgmedium/saveorder?pg_longid="+device.uuid+"&pid="+$pid+"&quantity="+$q,function(res){
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
            if(res['success']==true){
                $("#orderproduct").dialog("close");
            }else {
                alert("PG error number: "+ res['error']);
            }

        });

    })
});
```

$.mobile.loading('hide'); and $("#orderproduct").dialog("close"); didnot work

help me please

Comment: Are you sure that callback function is getting called at all? (Do you ever see the alert()?)

Comment: omg. $.get method run url fine but callback function didnot work why?

Comment: oh I shoud be use $.getJSON to json results on server

Comment: this not work with $.getJSON too

Comment: done. problem solved by sever side:headers in json